# Spring Boot JPA - @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true) is not refreshing the cache values

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot data JPA to update a column in my table.
My database is Postgres. I am trying to update the value of statusCode column in my DB. I am updating it to 6 from 1. 
 Below is the code for the same:

**Repository**

```
public interface MailRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<MailRecords, Integer> {

    // Fetch the rows which are new in status
    List<MailRecords> findTop100ByEmailStatusCode(int statusCode);

    // Update status to in-progress
    @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true) //, flushAutomatically = true
    @Query(value = "UPDATE users.usertbl SET statusCode = :inProgressStatusCode where " +
            "statusCode = 1 RETURNING *;", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<MailRecords> updateRecordsToInProgress(
            @Param("inProgressStatusCode") int inProgressStatusCode);
}
```

I am trying to get the updated rows by using RETURNING keyword in my native query which is supported by Postgres. I am assigning the updated rows returned by the query to a list and I am printing it in the console. But the updated list returns the old value for statusCode column i.e. 1 instead of the updated value i.e. 6
Below is the code for the same:

**ServiceClass**

```
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    @Autowired
    private MailRecordRepository mailRecordRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MailHandler mailHandler;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<MailRecords> getMailRecords() {
        return (List<MailRecords>) mailRecordRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<MailRecords> processEmailRecords() {
        //fetch records from DB which are in new status
        List<MailRecords> mailRecordsToBeSent = mailRecordRepository.findTop100ByEmailStatusCode(1);

        // update the status to in-progress
        //entityManager.clear();
        List<MailRecords> updatedMailRecords = mailRecordRepository.updateRecordsToInProgress(6);

        return updatedMailRecords;
    }
```

If I use entity manager's clear method, the updated values are reflected. But I am trying to understand why is the property `@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)` not clearing the cache values? Why do I have to call the `entityManager.clear()` explicitly?
Can anyone correct my understanding & point where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you please clarify the two versions of code you are comparing, the data that exists before you execute one of the version and what the results of the two versions is? The currently single version fo code with tons of commented stuf is confusing as hell.

Comment: @JensSchauder Updated the post by removing the commented lines & adding some more description!

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised that returning entities does work at all.

But I have a theory what might be going on, which you might be able to verify with a debugger:

1. The statement executes, updating the rows in the database
2. The statement returns a `ResultSet` with the updated values
3. The JPA implementation (Hibernate?) is ignoring everything but the ids and uses them to find the entities in the first level cache and returns those.
4. Spring Data JPA performs a flush and clears the first level cache. Then returns whatever it got from the JPA implementation in step 3.

You already found the workaround for that.

Comment: ```@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)``` should ideally clear/flush the objects in the first level cache as well right? Just trying to understand as to why it isn't working with the update query

Comment: Both flush and clear can't possibly work on anything but the 1st level cache. The problem is that it happens after your statement executes and results are obtained and therefor it doesn't have an effect on your results.